# data is null after fetching it from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make movies app for portfolio, I got an api with some data and I'm trying to fetch it with useEffect and then setting the state, I also use useContext hook for passing data to children props but the data is empty.

This is App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState, createContext } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Main } from "./components/Main/Main";

export const AppContext = createContext();

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star wars&apikey=459f1ce1").then((res) => {
      setData(res.data.Search);
    })
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppContext.Provider value={data}>
        <Main />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Main.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../../App";
import "./Main.css";

export const Main = () => {
  const { data } = useContext(AppContext);
  console.log(data)

  return <div>

  </div>;
};

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the `value` of the context is just the value of the `data` state. To be able to **destructure** the context change your value to an object containing the data.

```js
<AppContext.Provider value={{ data }}>
```

Comment: Yeah, i just fixed it atm!!